# c++ gives Segmentation Fault from text file of all 0's

Tags: c++, text, zero, fault

I'm writing a really simple code (or so I thought) that requires 2 text files to be read in.  One is full of a bunch of data points (of type double) and the other one happens to be a bunch of 0's (this is only SOMETIMES filled with 0's, sometimes it will be other numbers, so I need it to work for both 0's and non-zero's) like so:

```
0
0
0
..
```

I am reading these into vectors like so:

```
vector <double> E;
vector <double> M;
ifstream Ein("E.txt");
ifstream Min("M.txt");

while ( Ein >> value ) {
        E.push_back(value);
    }

     while ( Ein >> value ) {
        M.push_back(value);
    }
```

This works perfectly for the vector E (the one with actual values) after I comment out the M vector.  But whenever I include the M vector (all 0's) I get a segmentation fault when I run the program.

This means that C++ doesn't understand 0 as an input I guess? Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't the second `while` be using Min, not Ein?

Comment: None of the code here should trigger a segmentation fault even with the mistake of trying to read from `Ein` after it already reached EOF. I suspect the actual fault is the code following this we *don't* see where `M` is indexed via `operator[]` under the assumption (*never* a good idea) it contains data (which it does not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second while loop, did you want to have:

```
while ( Min >> value ) {
   M.push_back(value);
}
```

You're getting the segmentation fault because the Ein has hit EOF.  Also, you may want to close the input streams :)

Comment: Wow! I feel so stupid now, the whole time it was just that. The perils of using copy and paste I guess. And also, I did close the files, just later on in the code :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that you close the file stream, you're also reading from the same file twice, which is why you're getting the seg fault

Comment: Wow! I feel so stupid now, the whole time it was just that. The perils of using copy and paste I guess. And also, I did close the files, just later on in the code :) Thank you so much!